# Adding Title, Author, Subject, Keywords metadata with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, metadata, wkhtmltopdf

Is there a way to add metadata (e.g. Title, Author, Subject, Keywords) to a PDF when creating it with wkhtmltopdf from the command line via PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The many command line options for wkhtmltopdf are documented at http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt (also available by running `wkhtmltopdf -H`). You can set the title of a PDF via the `--title` global option. Currently there does not appear to be support for specifying author, subject, or keywords metadata.

Comment: As near as I can tell, --title does not set the title metadata field for the pdf either.

Comment: sorry `--title "Foo Bar"` works. thanks for the tip. (I checked the result of my changes on a different system where my changes where not deployed)